# PID for pure first order process (no time delay)

Tags: pid-controller

So I have to make a PID control for a pure first order process (DC-motor) to control the rotational speed. I cant use ZN because there is no time delay in the process and oscillation can't be achieved. I tried SIMC and Cohen-Coon but no results.  SIMC needs a delay. The proces 
$$
G(s) = \frac{0.042}{0.0001755 s + 0.001764}.
$$
I need PO<5%, not too much steering voltage < 10 volts, GM > 2, PM > 35deg and stability margin > 0.5

So.. Where should i start? What method would be good to tune my pid?

Comment: Jargon jargon jargon such as this: *PO<5%* and this: *SIMC* and, what does this mean: *not too much steering voltage < 10 volts*? Speak without jargon and state what you are trying to achieve more clearly.

Comment: i don't get what you mean by oscillation can't be achieved, in general when you have a pid controller you want a response without oscillation

Comment: ZN isn't particularly good, in any case. Add integral control and adjust the integral gain and proportional gain to get the speed of response and overshoot that you want. You shouldn't need a derivative term with a first order plant.

Comment: Notice that, with those requirements and no need to minimize the settling time, you should just find a "slow" PID that gives you an overdamped response.

Comment: @diegogmx OP is using a lot of jargon. Oscillation is deliberately induced as part of Ziegler-Nichols classic tuning technique from the 1940s.

Comment: If you can't get oscillations no matter what, what's to stop you from just turning the gain up to infinity and calling it done? Sag would approach zero for infinite gain so you could do it with just p term. I'm guessing either "it will never oscillate" is either wrong, or is this is some kind of unrealistic academic problem.